# When should the "container" form element be used?

Tags: forms

The System module defines the *container* form element, but that form element is not documented in the Form API Reference.

When should that form element be used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like it can be used when you want to wrap a part of the form in a div, for example to be able to add some classes to it.

Some examples from core are the following:

- [field_default_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.form.inc/function/field_default_form/7)

  ```
  // Also aid in theming of field widgets by rendering a classified container.
  $addition[$field_name] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array(
       'field-type-' . drupal_html_class($field['type']),
       'field-name-' . drupal_html_class($field_name),
       'field-widget-' . drupal_html_class($instance['widget']['type']),
      ),
    ),
    '#weight' => $instance['widget']['weight'],
  );
  ```
- [node_filter_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.admin.inc/function/node_filter_form/7)

  ```
  $form['filters']['status'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('clearfix')),
    '#prefix' => ($i ? '<div class="additional-filters">' . t('and where') . '</div>' : ''),
  );
  $form['filters']['status']['filters'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('filters')),
  );
  ```
- [search_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.module/function/search_form/7)

  ```
  $form['basic'] = array(
    '#type' => 'container',
    '#attributes' => array('class' => array('container-inline')),
  );
  ```

Forms in Drupal 6 often used `#prefix` and `#suffix` on the first/last element to do this; this is a lot better because it is easier to add additional items or move them around.

I could use this in a few places in my own contributed modules, actually. ;)

Comment: container type also implies a nesting level in form_state's input / values.

Comment: No, it does not. Only when explicitly specified as #tree => TRUE, the default is FALSE.

Comment: Ok, sorry. By casuality I was just adding a container in a field widget form and observed the nesting in $form_state. After your comment, I realized $element['tree'] comes as true. Thanks :)

Comment: Ah, yes, field widgets are always within a language and delta key, within that, they might be repeated, so #tree => TRUE is forced on them, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In D6, there were often times when you would need to add a `<div>` around a FAPI element (for example with `#ahah` / `#ajax`), so `container` is a more consistent solution in regards to the Forms API to this common pattern than adding a wrapper div using `#prefix`/`#suffix`.