# How to set page-specific CSS classes on the page callback build array?

Tags: 7, theming

I have a page callback like this:

```
function example_page() {
  $build = array();

  $build['#attributes'] = array('class' => array('example-class'));

  $build[] = array(
    '#markup' => '<p>My text here</p>',
  );

  return $build;
 }
```

As you can see, I have attempted to add classes to the div that wraps the output of the render array in the same fashion as the form API works. I have also tried setting `$build['classes']` or `$build['classes_array']`, but all of these tree syntaxes are ignored, and the content is simply wrapped in `<div class="content">`, which is not very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`#attributes` is the correct property, but the problem is that $build itself is not actually an render element (unless make it one), it's just a collection of render elements.

To make it an actual render element, you have to set the #type property to for example 'container'. That is nothing more than a div with attributes that contains other elements. See [When should the "container" form element be used?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/381/when-should-the-container-form-element-be-used) and [theme_container()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_container/7).

You can however not affect the mentioned content div, that is outside of your control. Adding a container will add a new div inside that one.

Comment: Setting `$build['#type'] = 'container';` seems to make no difference. Was that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your module is called 'example', you can do this:

```
function example_preprocess_node(&$variables, $hook) {
  $variables['content_attributes_array']['class'][] = 'my_class';
}
```

Comment: Ah, a small correction - actually in your case (custom page) it would be example_preprocess_block(), not node...

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer which Berdir gave you could also look at using `#theme_wrappers` to wrap the element using a theme function. I think it may have similar results.

```
<div class="content">
```

is a pretty standard element in Drupal to define the page content. You may find you have unwanted side affects if you remove it.

Comment: I wasn't aiming to remove it, just add another class to it, to avoid having yet another div-wrapper inside it :)